# Create front end website for Google App Engine app

Tags: html, jsp, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have created a Google App Engine website using the tutorials and have uploaded it to `AAA.appspot.com`. But I would like to create a `www.AAA.com` website and pull data out of the App Engine. In Google App Engine settings you can add `www.AAA.com` to access Google App Engine API. What I need is a tool or tutorial recommendation to get me started on developing `www.AAA.com`. I'm very new to website development but am an experience programmer. So I have the Java servlet code setup but I cannot get the front end to connect to it.

In my html form can I do something like `<form action="http://AAA.appspot.com/GET_Request_URL" method="get">`? What about `post` requests?

Comment: I'm probably missing the point, but why not just map `www.AAA.com` as custom domain to your `AAA.appspot.com` app? See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl

Comment: Ha...I did not know about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One classic way to connect an HTML front-end to an App Engine back-end is by using the Google JavaScript client library https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

Romin Irani has nice tutorials on this method, see https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-1-b571ad6c7cd2#.sbsqvfu3n and in particular Part 4 https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-4-37ea3aac7948#.ivyo2i4pb

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. But I prefer doing it in below way, using reference paths (or) app handler names rather than full URLs

```
<form action="/mainpage" method="post">
```

You can use the app handlers only if the code is in GAE.   Otherwise, as I said you can do the way you are currently doing by providing complete URLs. It will work for both POST and GET as long as URL has POST and GET methods implemented.

Comment: I can only do this if the file this code is in is uploaded to Google App Engine right? If I'm hosting this file somewhere else, this wouldn't work?

Comment: Yes you can use the reference paths or app handlers only if the code is in GAE.   Otherwise, as I said you can do the way you are doing by providing complete URLs. It will work for both POST and GET as long as URL has methods implemented